# NoSuchMethodException in liferay portlet while adding data

Tags: jsp, model-view-controller, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I am using liferay and i have created my own portlet which have just add functionality.but some how i am having error in adding books

this is my view.jsp

```
<%@ include file="/init.jsp"%>


<%
    Restaurant resto = (Restaurant) request.getAttribute("Restaurant");
    if (resto == null) {
        resto = new RestaurantImpl();

        resto.setTable_Count(1);
    }
%>
<liferay-portlet:actionURL name="addreRestaurant" var="addreRestaurantURL"></liferay-portlet:actionURL>

<aui:form action="<%=addreRestaurantURL.toString() %>" method="post" name="fm">

    <aui:fieldset>
        <%-- <liferay-ui:error key="title-required" message="title-required" /> --%>
        <p>
            <aui:input name="Name" label="Name" type="text"
                value="<%=resto.getName()%>"></aui:input>
        </p>
        <%-- <liferay-ui:error key="author-required" message="author-required" /> --%>
        <p>
            <aui:input name="Location" label="Location" type="text"
                value="<%=resto.getLocation() %>"></aui:input>
        </p>
        <%-- <liferay-ui:error key="pages-required" message="pages-required" />
        <liferay-ui:error key="pages-cannot-be-zero"
            message="pages-cannot-be-zero" /> --%>
        <p>
            <aui:input name="table_count" label="Table_count" type="text"
                value="<%=String.valueOf(resto.getTable_Count()) %>"></aui:input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <aui:input name="room_count" label="Room_count" type="text"
                value="<%=String.valueOf(resto.getRoom_Count()) %>"></aui:input>

        </p>
        <p>
            <aui:input name="reseller_ID" label="Reseller_ID" type="text"
                value="<%=String.valueOf(resto.getReseller_ID()) %>"></aui:input>

        </p>

        <p>
                <aui:button class="aui-button-input" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <aui:button class="aui-button-input" type="reset" value="Reset" />
            </p>

            </aui:fieldset>
</aui:form>

<liferay-ui:search-container emptyResultsMessage="no-restaurant" delta="5">
</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

And following is my service implementation class

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2000-2012 Liferay, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
 * the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
 * Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
 * any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
 * FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Lesser General Public License for more
 * details.
 */

package com.test.service.impl;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.test.model.Restaurant;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.PortalException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;

import com.test.service.base.RestaurantServiceBaseImpl;

/**
 * The implementation of the restaurant remote service.
 *
 * <p>
 * All custom service methods should be put in this class. Whenever methods are added, rerun ServiceBuilder to copy their definitions into the {@link com.test.service.RestaurantService} interface.
 *
 * <p>
 * This is a remote service. Methods of this service are expected to have security checks based on the propagated JAAS credentials because this service can be accessed remotely.
 * </p>
 *
 * @author bhavik.kama
 * @see com.test.service.base.RestaurantServiceBaseImpl
 * @see com.test.service.RestaurantServiceUtil
 */
public class RestaurantServiceImpl extends RestaurantServiceBaseImpl {
    public Restaurant addreRestaurant(Restaurant restoParam) {
        Restaurant restoVar;

        try {
            restoVar = restaurantPersistence.create((int) counterLocalService
                    .increment(Restaurant.class.toString()));
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return restoVar = null;
        }

        try {
            resourceLocalService.addResources(restoParam.getCompanyId(),
                    restoParam.getGroupId(), restoParam.getUserId(),
                    Restaurant.class.getName(), restoParam.getPrimaryKey(),false,
                    true, true);
        } catch (PortalException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return restoVar = null;
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return restoVar = null;
        }

        restoVar.setLocation(restoParam.getLocation());
        restoVar.setCompanyId(restoParam.getCompanyId());
        restoVar.setResto_ID(restoParam.getResto_ID());
        restoVar.setUserId(restoParam.getUserId());
        restoVar.setGroupId(restoParam.getGroupId());
        restoVar.setName(restoParam.getName());
        restoVar.setRoom_Count(restoParam.getRoom_Count());
        restoVar.setTable_Count(restoParam.getRoom_Count());
        restoVar.setUserId(restoParam.getUserId());

        try {
            return restaurantPersistence.update(restoVar, false);
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return restoVar = null;
        }
    }
    public List<Restaurant> getAllerRestaurants() {
        try {
            return restaurantPersistence.findAll();
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }

    public List<Restaurant> getAllreRestaurants(long groupId, String title) {
        try {
            return restaurantPersistence.findByGroupId(groupId);
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
}
```

And following error i am facing its hwoing that its cant find method of addreRestaurant but i have that method.so where am doing mistake?

Error is as follows:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet TabsTest Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.addreRestaurant(javax.portlet.ActionRequest, javax.portlet.ActionResponse)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605).....
```

As follows is my Portlet Class Method to addRestaurant..

```
package com.test.portlet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import com.test.model.Restaurant;
import com.test.service.RestaurantServiceUtil;
import com.test.util.RestaurantActionUtil;
import com.test.util.RestaurantValidator;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SessionErrors;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SessionMessages;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.Validator;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.WebKeys;
import com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay;
import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;

/**
 * Portlet implementation class BooksPortlet
 */
public class RestaurantPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(RestaurantPortlet.class);
    private static String errorJSP="/jsps/error.jsp" ;

    public void addRestaurant(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {

        log.info("Inside addRegistration");
        List<String> errors=new ArrayList<String>();
        Restaurant resto=RestaurantActionUtil.getRestaurantFromRequest(request);
        boolean bookValid=RestaurantValidator.validateBook(resto, errors);
        if(bookValid) {
            log.info(resto);
            Restaurant test=RestaurantServiceUtil.addreRestaurant(resto);
            if(test==null) {
                log.error("REsto was Found Null");
                //response.setRenderParameter("jspPage", errorJSP);
                return ;
            }
            SessionMessages.add(request,"book-added");
            return ;
        }
        else {
             for (String error : errors) {
                    SessionErrors.add(request, error);
                }
                SessionErrors.add(request, "error-while-adding");
                request.setAttribute("Restaurant",resto);
                return ;
        }

    }

    /*
    public void deleteBooks(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {

        long bookId = ParamUtil.getLong(request, "bookId");
        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(
                WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

        if (Validator.isNotNull(bookId)) {
            BooksLocalServiceUtil.deleteBooks(bookId, themeDisplay.getCompanyId());
            SessionMessages.add(request, "book-deleted");

        } else {
            SessionErrors.add(request, "error-deleting");

        }

    }

*/
}
```

This is my new error trace...

```
14:16:50,870 INFO  [RestaurantPortlet:35] Inside addRegistration
14:16:50,872 INFO  [RestaurantPortlet:40] {Resto_ID=0, Name=dasd, Location=ads, Room_Count=2, Table_Count=1, userId=10196, companyId=10154, groupId=10180, Reseller_ID=55}
com.liferay.portal.ResourceActionsException: There are no actions associated with the resource com.test.model.Restaurant
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.ResourceLocalServiceImpl.validate(ResourceLocalServiceImpl.java:1348)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.ResourceLocalServiceImpl.addResources(ResourceLocalServiceImpl.java:845)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.ResourceLocalServiceImpl.addResources(ResourceLocalServiceImpl.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

...........
.............
14:16:50,878 ERROR [RestaurantPortlet:43] REsto was Found Null

My Action Resource mapping xml..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<resource-action-mapping>

    <portlet-resource>
        <portlet-name>RestaurantPortlet</portlet-name>
        <permissions>
            <supports>
                <action-key>addRestaurant</action-key>
                <action-key>VIEW</action-key>
            </supports>
            <community-defaults>
                <action-key>VIEW</action-key>
            </community-defaults>
            <guest-defaults>
                <action-key>VIEW</action-key>
            </guest-defaults>

            <guest-unsupported>
                <action-key>addRestaurant</action-key>
            </guest-unsupported>
        </permissions>
    </portlet-resource>

    <model-resource>
        <model-name>com.test.Restaurant</model-name>
        <portlet-ref>
            <portlet-name>RestaurantPortlet</portlet-name>
        </portlet-ref>
        <permissions>
            <supports>
                <action-key>addRestaurant</action-key>

                <action-key>VIEW</action-key>
            </supports>
            <community-defaults>
                <action-key>VIEW</action-key>
            </community-defaults>
            <guest-defaults>
                <action-key>VIEW</action-key>
            </guest-defaults>
            <guest-unsupported>

            </guest-unsupported>
        </permissions>
    </model-resource>

</resource-action-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the things done at last...in database there is no entry about my addRestaurant action in actionrescources table.

After lots of R&D have found that.. I  have to just manually add the addRestaurant entry in that table and it just worked.

I wiil now be searching  how its not adding entry to resourceaction automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your method : `public Restaurant addreRestaurant(Restaurant restoParam)`
The method that is required by the portlet: `addreRestaurant(javax.portlet.ActionRequest,javax.portlet.ActionResponse)`

Comment: ya i have that method in portlet too..just see my updated question i have that method in my portlet class.still am having that error

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.addreRestaurant`  
Is your class bound correctly to the view? (Check your portlet.xml)

Comment: Thanx.have some issue regarding bounding the portlet..just gave my portlet package again in portlet.xml and then rebuild the service and the error is gone.but got another error but that is diffrent soemthng goes wrong while adding ..Error is as follows

Comment: 09:31:26,252 INFO  [RestaurantPortlet:35] Inside addRegistration
09:31:26,253 INFO  [RestaurantPortlet:40] {Resto_ID=0, Name=, Location=, Room_Count=0, Table_Count=0, userId=10196, companyId=10154, groupId=10180, Reseller_ID=0}
com.liferay.portal.ResourceActionsException: There are no actions associated with the resource com.test.model.Restaurant

Comment: is this related to your question?   you could generate a new question and provide the full stacktrace

Comment: Yes this is realted to this anyways i have created question ..please guide me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638016/resourceactionsexception-while-adding-the-value-in-database-in-my-own-portal

Comment: you are still stuck at the same portlet but i dont think that the issue is related ;)

Answer (score 1):

your mvc class method name is **addRestaurant**(), while your jsp requires:

name="**addreRestaurant**"

method names are differents :)

Comment: thats not my problem i have intentionaly did that way  <liferay-portlet:actionURL name="addRestaurant" var="addRestaurantURL"></liferay-portlet:actionURL>  here i am giving my portlet class method and in my portlet class i assign the addrerestaurant method of my baseimpl class with ..Restaurant test=RestaurantServiceUtil.addreRestaurant(resto); so thats not the reason of error

Comment: ok, but the  liferay-portlet:actionURL name="addreRestaurant"  must match a method inside the mvc implementation.
The error says: com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.addreRestaurant(....) .... 

you must change the jsp code with: <liferay-portlet:actionURL name="addRestaurant" var="addreRestaurantURL"></liferay-portlet:actionURL>

Comment: Ok i have change the way you said but having same error .please see my updated question content at the end where i have put my error trace.please do check

Comment: added new answer for better visibility

Answer (score 1):

Your new stacktrace is related to a different error.
The problem is inside the RestauranteServiceImpl.addreRestaurant(), more specifically the snippet:

```
resourceLocalService.addResources(restoParam.getCompanyId(),
                    restoParam.getGroupId(), restoParam.getUserId(),
                    Restaurant.class.getName(), restoParam.getPrimaryKey(),false,
                    true, true);
```

this means you have no resource action related to your class or your portlet. Have you defined your resource-action-mapping  ?

Comment: yes i have define that just take a look at my question..at last i m givng u the snippet of my resource action mapping code

Comment: sorry i didn't noticed the last snippet. But again the `<model-name>com.test.Restaurant</model-name>` isn't matching the entity you are about to add to resources, as the exception says: `There are no actions associated with the resource com.test.MODEL.Restaurant`....

Answer (score 0):

Running

> service-builder

fixed the problem for me.